# Chrome Extension for Twittch API give me an error about Content security policy

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension, twitch-api

I'm doing a chrome extension for my viewers to know when i'm on stream or not, 
so i've done it but it returns an error

First i've tried to do it with JQuery XMLHttpRequest, but I found out that the JSONP was better for those extensions, so I done it with JSONP requests like this

```js
checkStream();

setInterval(function(){
  checkStream();
}, 5000);

function checkStream() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/cew_kuhaku?client_id=myclientid',
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {},
    // Work with the response
    success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response ); // server response

              $("#json").html(response)
              if(response["stream"] == null){
                $("#info").html("Kuhaku n'est pas en stream");
                      chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "img/off.png"});
              }else {
                $("#info").html("Kuhaku est en stream")
                      chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "img/on.png"});
              }
    }
  });
}
```

My manifest looks like this :

```
{
  "manifest_version":2,
  "name":"CEW Kuhaku Streaming",
  "version":"1.0",
  "description":"Extension de stream de CEW Kuhaku",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup":"index.html"
  },
  "icons":{
    "64" : "img/on.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery.js", "background.js"]
  }
}
```

Here is my index.html

```html
<h1>Stream CEW Kuhaku</h1>
<p id="info">Kuhaku est en live</p>
<p id="json"></p>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

I expect to verify my stream status but i got this :

```
Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Comment: Just as a side-note: This probably won't work for your users, since the rate limit of Twitch (without bearer token) is 30 calls per minute, **per client-ID** (the client-ID of **your** application in this case).

Comment: i've updated it to 1 request/min, for now it's a small comunity

Comment: While it's not explicitly stated what happens if the rate limit is violated on a regular base and over extended amount of time (which would happen, once you exceed 30 people having this extension installed and them having the browser open), I can imagine that they might suspend the account. I hope that you're using a different account than your streaming account, for this.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add content security policy configuration to your manifest.json

```
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://example.com; object-src 'self'"
```

Comment: did you just copy and paste what i added or did you update the example.com references?

Comment: I copied and paste it, and i tried by puting localhost instead

Comment: I've added my index.html to my original post

Comment: is there an external js script being loaded anywhere? dont see why youd be getting that error with the 2 local js scripts in your index.html

Comment: I only load the 2 local scripts

Comment: might have to do with the twitch api callback remove the CSP changes to manifest as try adding “permissions”:[“https://api.twitch.tv”] to the manifest

Comment: same problem, what could I put instead of the exemple.com ?